# What happens if a file is renamed during a copy operation using cp on linux?

Tags: cp, corruption, concurrency, integrity

So I want to use...

```
cp /var/log/somelogs/* ./temp
```

... to copy some log files to a temporary folder and analyse them. The problem is that the process generating the log files isn't under my control and every so often it implements log rotation - as often as every 15 seconds at busy times! Eventually the cp is going to happen while log rotation is also happening. I am curious what happens when this happens.

While I can happily wait a few fractions of a second more to get a good read of this folder how can I tell when I've got a bad one? Is cp likely to terminate / crash with an error code? Will it print something to stdout? Or might it silently pass me a potentially corrupted / misnamed folder worth of logs?

Sadly the fs is ext4 and also out of my control so I can't leverage snapshotting, boo :/

Answer (score 2):

The wildcards on the command line ("`/var/log/somelogs/*`") are expanded first (before `cp` starts executing). If the resulting list of files contains a filename that no longer exists (due to log rotation running while `cp` was copying earlier files), `cp` will complain, try the next file, and return a non-zero exit status (`bash` variable `$?`). See `man cp`.

See the wildcard expansion with;

```
echo cp /var/log/somelogs/* ./temp
```

Comment: Thanks. The more I think about it the big problem is that logrotate renames all the files and the list only gets longer so by the time cp reaches file #10 it might be reading what WAS file #9 when it started. Unless cp gets filesystem handles for every file before it starts which would surprise me.

Comment: The list of files that `cp` gets is expanded once, by the shell, before `cp` starts. Filenames created after the expansion are not added to `cp`'s. parameters. `cp` never sees the `*` (unless no match).